# Direct Login to windows without grub menu

Tags: dual-boot

I have successfully installed dual boot ubuntu 18.04 alongside with Windows.But when I am restarting the system it directly goes to windows 10 without showing grub menu

Comment: I recommend boot from Ubuntu live usb and run Boot-repair.

Answer (score 0):

This have to be set in BIOS settings. 
In BIOS go to BOOT and put Ubuntu on the first place.
Ubuntu should ask every time, which system do you want to use.

Comment: You cannot acces GRUB from the bios settings. The thing you mean is Boot Priority. That has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I did not say, you can acces it :-) Putting Ubuntu on the first place, will cause that Ubuntu GRUB will be launched everytime, when computer is turned on.

Comment: ... and if you put usb first....